# Name of the "s" parameter in Ungar's theory of hyperbolic geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, terminology, hyperbolic-geometry

I have done a [R package](https://github.com/stla/gyro) which implements Ungar's approach to hyperbolic geometry, for the hyperboloid model. In this theory, there is a parameter $s>0$ which controls the curvature of the hyperbolic segments:

[image]

Ungar's theory is not very well-known. An intro and a reference can be found [on my blog](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/hyperbolicPolyhedra.html).

I'm wondering whether this parameter $s$ has a devoted name? Would you know? I know Ungar's theory but I'm ignorant in classical hyperbolic geometry in the hyperboloid model, maybe this parameter also appears in the classical theory?

Comment: Perhaps the paper arXiv 1908.10389 is of some interest.
E.g. a formula for the hyperbolic midpoint of two points in the unit disk is given there.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of relativistic mechanics, the parameter $s$ is the speed of light, see for example [The Intrinsic Beauty, Harmony and Interdisciplinarity in Einstein Velocity Addition Law:
Gyrogroups and Gyrovector Spaces](https://mir.kashanu.ac.ir/article_13636_01f4395f33b5311416ea86da2a1e38d4.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. But "speed of light" is not for the case of the Einstein gyrovector space only?